# What is the meaning of property "Browse to URL" in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am poking around our Visual Studio project, and I would like to know what the "Browse to URL" property is, and how it is used.

Comment: Ummm you have a url in your code, if you click it, your internet browser/VS will go to it...

Comment: @Nick What does it mean if you edit it?  Why is it not read-only? Why is it editable for a css file? Where is the information stored?

Comment: It is stored in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

My **guess** is that it is the URL Visual Studio will browse to when you start debugging with that view active. So by default you could have a product ID in the URL when you debug the product view for testing purposes.

Reason for assuming that is in the Shared folder the _ on the _Layout partial view leaves the "Browse to URL" value blank. So for pages that are not navigable you use a leading _ and they will default to the homepage when debugging if that view in active in Visual Studio.

So my **guess** is that it is a local feature for debugging and testing only?